# Gaming keyboard G265 not responsive and backlight keeps flashing

Tags: usb, keyboard, hardware-failure, power

My new Genius G265 gaming keyboard is not responsive and keeps flashing the backlight. In Windows I hear repeating ding sounds as if I removed the keyboard and plugged it back in. If I manage to turn off the backlight (with a Fn key), flashing and sounds stop and the keyboard works fine. But as soon as I turn backlight back on, it starts flashing again.

**EDIT:**

Looks like the keyboard lights are drawing more power than USB is able to provide, though an external 2.5" drive is working fine in the same port. I suppose the keyboard isn't more power hungry than a hard disk? I also tried to plug the keyboard into different ports with same result.

The computer is custom built with following components:
Win 8.1, Cooler Master K350 600W, GIGABYTE Z87-HD3, i5-4670K, GIGABYTE N760OC-4GD, 8GB RAM, Intel SSD 520, Seagate Barracuda 7200

My question is whether this is a faulty keyboard or is something wrong with the PC (motherboard, component selection, build)?

**EDIT 2:**

I'm a bit concerned about the graphic card power. It requires both PCI-e 8 and PCI-e 6 pin cables to be connected, however the PSU only has one. The other one I got through an adapter from two peripheral 4 pin connectors (on the same cable). Could this be drawing too much power from 5V supply?

**EDIT 3:**

I tried to connect the keyboard through a powered hub and it works!

However I don't understand why it still works even if I disconnect external power from the [hub](http://trust.com/14789). Can someone explain this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You've done a go job describing the problem. We need a little more information to be able to help you. Please [edit] your question to tell us what you've tried to resolve this, where you've gotten stuck and what your question is. It would also be helpful to know the computer info and OS.

Comment: Since the keyboard isn't working in other USB ports and an external drive does work in the port where the keyboard does not, it sounds like it could be a faulty keyboard IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know if the keyboard is defective, connect it to another computer to see if the problem is consistent.

If it is, contact [Genius](http://www.geniusnet.com/Genius/wSite/ct?xItem=57771&ctNode=134) for support.

If it works properly, then you have something wrong with your system. There is no way for us to be able to tell you exactly what. Make sure you have the latest BIOS and/or drivers for your motherboard.

Comment: I see. Perhaps connecting the keyboard through a powered USB hub would also answer the question about insufficient power from USB (I'll try).

Comment: That's a good idea to ensure it's getting enough power. Is it plugged into a hub now, or direct to the motherboard?